# undefined reference when using templates

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors

Keep on getting undefined reference which other answers say should be linking issue. Am I not compiling this correctly? Or is there something wrong in the code? I've tried throwing main into stack.cpp and it compiles and runs fine, but I'm not sure what else needs to be done to link main.o and stack.o and why it suddenly is throwing a fit now that I've added this one file.

stack.h:

```
#ifndef STACK_INCLUDED
#define STACK_INCLUDED

#include <cstddef>

template<typename T> struct Node {
  Node(T _data, Node<T> * _next) : data(_data), next(_next) {}
  T data;
  Node<T> *next;
};

template<class T>
class Stack {
 private:
  Node<T> *first;
 public:
  Stack(void);
  bool isEmpty(void);
  void push(T n);
  T pop(void);
};

#endif
```

stack.cpp:

```
#include "stack.h"

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(void) {
  first = NULL;
}

template<class T>
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty(void) {
  return first == NULL;
}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T n) {
  Node<T> *oldfirst = first;
  Node<T> *newfirst = new Node<T>(n, oldfirst);
  first = newfirst;
  first->next = oldfirst;
}

template<class T>
T Stack<T>::pop(void) {
  T data = first->data;
  first = first->next;
  return data;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  Stack<int> s;

  if (!s.isEmpty()) {
    cout << "not empty" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Try to compile:

```
$ g++ stack.cpp -c
$ g++ main.cpp -c
$ g++ main.o stack.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `Stack<int>::Stack()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `Stack<int>::isEmpty()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use separate compilation with templates like this. The compiler needs to see the template definitions (the template function bodies) at the point of use, or it doesn't know how to generate code for the `int` instance of `Stack<T>::Stack()` (etc.). You could explicitly ask for the instances in your stack.cpp, but you are better off moving the function definitions into the header file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the entire template class definition in the header.

Answer (score 1):

You can seperate implementation from header but you should use 'extern templates' from C++11.

Comment: That works, but it requires providing an explicit specialization for every template use, which gets pretty tedious in general coding. It's more often used as an optimization. For example, the standard library's `basic_string` is almost always used as `basic_string<char>`, and rather than have the compiler instantiate that in every translation unit that mentions it and then have the linker throw away all but one, it's usually instantiated in one source file in the library, and the `<string>` header declares it as an extern template. Other uses of `basic_string` go through the usual mechanism.